# Testing SharedPrefernces in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to test if my method calls SharedPreferences's put method. Is that possible in unit testing?

In general: this is method I would like to test. I want to verify if unit was set.

```
Future _setUnit(String unit) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('unit', unit);
}
```

I know there is SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues method but I don't think it would anyhow help me.